# Execute a script compiled on a different PC

Tags: linux, expect, compiler

If I have a compiled expect script, can I run it on a PC with no expect installed?

Comment: That depends on where you compiled it and where you want to run it.  Can you please _edit_ your question and include information about the operating system and compilers you used to build it and the operating system where you want to run it?

Comment: Compiled script?? If it's a script, it's not compiled! If else it's a binary tool for wich sources are somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**

You need to have `expect` script on target machine.
Since, `expect` script expects **expect** to be available before executing.

Consider it as running `bash` script without installing **bash**